# JSON for loop only listing the last record

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm trying to store the state of vms in two servers and power the running vms down.  Here is the code:

The script:

```
s = paramiko.SSHClient()
s.load_system_host_keys()
s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
s.connect(hostname, port, username, password)
command = 'xe vm-list'
(stdin, stdout, stderr) = s.exec_command(command)
output = stdout.read().decode("UTF-8")
#print(output)
x = "{\""
x += output.replace("\n", ",").strip()
x = x.replace(",,,",",")
x = x.replace("Control domain on host: ","Control domain on host-")
x = x.replace("           ", "")
x = x.replace("     ","")
x = x.replace(" ( RO)","")
x = x.replace(" ( RW)","")
x = x.replace("    ","")
x = x.replace(":","\":\"")
x = x.replace(",","\",\"")
x = x.replace("\":\" ","\":\"")
x += "}"
x = x.replace("\",\"}","\"}")

print("x:" + x + "**************")


the_dict = json.loads(x)
#print("The JSON:  " + the_dict)
print("Length: %d" % len (the_dict))
for (k,v) in the_dict.items():
    print(k, ":", v)



s.close()
```

Results:

> x:{"uuid":"a02cee47-4990-46c4-9917-d21a253f365d","name-label":"Control domain on host-xcp-Zimm2","power-state":"running","uuid":"f87a9e4f-ce29-7b89-fdce-21e5b90146c7","name-label":"Kali","power-state":"halted","uuid":"62f6d6d1-3825-a8ee-554b-08069ad66629","name-label":"Ansible","power-state":"running","uuid":"25778208-cac7-d37f-6be0-c0db3b3be417","name-label":"Test_VM","power-state":"halted","uuid":"488a2ecf-8183-cf4a-5a98-a9162778a02f","name-label":"Xen Orchestra","power-state":"running","uuid":"aa4867d3-13f1-5271-8313-fff11e01a2b2","name-label":"HomeSeer4","power-state":"running","uuid":"251117aa-704f-38bc-c0dc-85af2637b46e","name-label":"Dashboard","power-state":"running","uuid":"f7cb6983-f985-2adf-e064-0f8b62e24aff","name-label":"Truenas","power-state":"running","uuid":"2a18d0b7-eff1-4814-993a-5cd2e3787ab3","name-label":"Control domain on host-zimm-xenserver","power-state":"running","uuid":"aa879de1-2ff3-072f-a9aa-f40246af272b","name-label":"10gig pfSense","power-state":"running","uuid":"65381e2c-b98f-702d-238a-4241c2cc8b1c","name-label":"Zoneminder","power-state":"running","uuid":"3cff72c3-56f9-656f-b385-b6ce669b41e4","name-label":"dhcp server","power-state":"halted","uuid":"bdbf7de4-a3cf-3c06-017a-625e05f18a9a","name-label":"Home Media Control","power-state":"halted","uuid":"f4bca177-1bec-b0d0-6638-489428fb90d5","name-label":"Windows 10 sync machine","power-state":"halted"}

```
Length: 3
uuid : f4bca177-1bec-b0d0-6638-489428fb90d5
name-label :Windows 10
sync machine  power-state : halted
```

Do I have something wrong with my formatting to cause it to only recognize the last record in that JSON string?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As I see there should be list of objects with uuid, name-label and power-state but it is all merged in single object. Can you provide original response received over SSH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is, you've **multiple duplicate keys on your JSON** i.e x ([check it here](https://jsonlint.com/)) So when you try this

```
the_dict = json.loads(x)
```

it discards the **duplicate keys** and treats it as below,

```
{
  "uuid": "f4bca177-1bec-b0d0-6638-489428fb90d5",
  "name-label": "Windows 10 sync machine",
  "power-state": "halted"
}
```

That's why when you use this,

```
print("Length: %d" % len (the_dict))
for (k,v) in the_dict.items():
    print(k, ":", v)
```

It returns below output which is right,

```
Length: 3
uuid : f4bca177-1bec-b0d0-6638-489428fb90d5
name-label :Windows 10
sync machine  power-state : halted
```